# Add 3sec fade out of the last frame to a video

Tags: ffmpeg

For example, given a video 1.mp4 (no audio) of 17s, output a 20s video where the last frame fades out.

What I came up with:

1. Extract the last frame

`ffmpeg -sseof -1 -i 1.mp4 -update true last.png`

2. Create a 3s fade-out video

`ffmpeg -r 60 -loop 1 -t 3 -i last.png -vf "fade=out:st=0:d=3" 2.mp4 -y`

3. concatenate

ffmpeg -f concat -i list.txt -c copy 3.mp4 -y

where list.txt is

```
file '1.mp4'
file '2.mp4'
```

I was wondering if there's an easier method, e.g. something base on

[How to use ffmpeg to fade in/out a veriable frame rate video clip with unknown duration](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/23340/how-to-use-ffmpeg-to-fade-in-out-a-veriable-frame-rate-video-clip-with-unknown-d)

Comment: No shortcut while using ffmpeg. You have to write complex_filter to complete your task.

Comment: How do you do it with filter_complex?